# Open a context menu via command binding

Tags: wpf, binding, command

I'm trying to bind a button to open its context menu on a left click. I'm aware how to do this programmatically, but is there a way to do this with a default command binding?

I've currently got:

```
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.ContextMenu">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem ...
```

but no such luck... if I do this then the button is disabled. I guess this indicates that the command cannot be executed, but why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in few ways and here are two of them:

**1) pure XAML**

```
<Button Content="My Button">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="ABC"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

**2) using event**

```
<Button Content="My Button" Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu >
            <MenuItem Header="ABC"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ContextMenu contextMenu = (sender as Button).ContextMenu;
   contextMenu.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
   contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```